# What is a writing that writes down every single word what one is thinking, called?

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember that there was one technique of English writing that writes down
every single word what one thinks. I forgot what this type of writing is called, does anyone knows the word?

"umm, I think yesterday was raining, eh.. but oh wait, no, It's incorrect. It was cloudy......."

Comment: [Filler words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_%28linguistics%29)

Comment: I think you mean "Being David Foster Wallace."

Comment: Stream of consciousness.

Comment: famous example is the very end of James Joyce's Ulysses, "Molly Bloom's Soliloquy"

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**[Stream of consciousness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_of_consciousness_(narrative_mode))**  is, I think,  what you are referring to.

> - Stream of consciousness is a narrative mode, or device, that seeks "to
>   depict the multitudinous thoughts and feelings which pass through the
>   mind. Another term for it is 'interior monologue'."

(Wikipedia)

Comment: bingo, that was the word I was trying to remember. thank you.

Comment: @user126125 you're welcome

Comment: However, stream of consciousness does not necessarily imply the inclusion of null words such "umm" and "eh" which you used in your example.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast The multitudinous thoughts and feelings which pass through my mind often include many umms and ehs. I worry now that I'm unusual in that way.

Comment: Not to worry. It's weenies like James Joyce who apparently think in complete, uninterrupted sentences and paragraphs who make life difficult for the rest of us.

Answer (score 13):

As a technique, this is called *[free writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_writing)*. As a literary style, it is called *stream of consciousness* (as pointed out above) or *écriture automatique*, when referring to the French surrealist movement around Breton. Colloquially, I have also heard people refer to it as *brain dump(ing)*, but this has a somewhat different [connotation](http://www.lifehack.org/articles/productivity/how-to-do-the-ultimate-brain-dump.html).

Comment: +1 for the extra info. "Brain Dump" makes me think of "Brain Fart"; only more... substantial.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are thinking of [stream of consciousness](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stream-of-consciousness?showCookiePolicy=true).

Answer (score 0):

I would also propose that this is an 'Inner Monologue' or 'Interior Monologue', the thought-stream from within your head.

> **interior monologue**
>
> A passage of writing presenting a character's inner thoughts and emotions in a direct, sometimes disjointed or fragmentary manner.
>
> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interior+monologue

The term can be used in a literary setting as above, or to describe your own internal voice.